# C++ code in GPU

Tags: c++, gpu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [write code to run in GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453049/write-code-to-run-in-gpu)

I have already a code writen in C++ but it's really slow so I want to run it at the GPU. Is that possible? , how?

Comment: I promise you if your C++ code is that slow there is probably an easier solution than running it on your GPU.

Comment: Link to duplicated question does not work anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, not easily.  You can find the CUDA library which allows you GPU access [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-zone).

From there, you'll find a GPU API that allows you to interact with it.  I haven't done this myself, but from what I understand, it's not a very straightforward port-my-code-over process.  It does make your code fly if you successfully do it though.